# HTML / CSS - Issue Aligning Elements in Block

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm having a bit of trouble aligning a few elements and setting the correct height.

Here's my HTML:

```html
<?php
require 'connect.php';
require 'variables.php';
include 'articles.php';
$pagename = "Login";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $pagename; ?> ~ <?php echo $hotelname; ?></title>
<?php require 'global.php'; ?>
</head>

<body>
<header class="view"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" class="logo"></header>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
<li><a href="staff.php">Staff</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<section class="main">
<article>
<header class="title"><?php echo $articleOneTitle; ?></header>
<section class="content"><?php echo $articleOneContent; ?></section>
</article>
<sidebar>
<header class="title">Login</header>
<section>
<?php
require 'login.php';
if (isset($_GET["msg"]) && $_GET["msg"] == 'failed') {
echo "<p>Wrong Username / Password</p>";
}
?>
</section>
</sidebar>
</section>
<section><h1>TEST</h1></section>
<footer><?php require 'footer.php'; ?></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my CSS (excluding unnecessary elements):

```css
section.main {
 display: block;
 width: 75%;
 min-height: 200%;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px;
}
article {
 display: block;
 width: 50%;
 background: #F1F0F0;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}
sidebar {
 display: block;
 width: 215px;
 background: #F1F0F0;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: 55.6%;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}
footer {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Now, the problem I'm having is with the `<section class="main">` element. As you can see, `<sidebar>` and `<article>` are within `<section class="main">`. I've gotten those to align properly, however I'm trying to get section.main to adjust it's height according to the height of the elements inside of it. I've tried setting it to height: auto;, but that didn't work. The reason I need this to happen is currently, the elements immediately below `<section class="main">` such as `<footer>` are being covered by the elements inside of it. I can't just set the height to any number like "200px" because the article changes and it can be smaller, bigger, etc. I really need it to adjust it's height according to the elements inside of it.

If you're still clueless as to what I mean by this, just check out my actual page;
[Click Here!](http://cms.wreckmodz.com/)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your position:absolute causing this issue, try to avoid being use position absolute in such situation.

You can use float:left; to make the align for example:

```
.sidebar { float:left;}
.article { float:left;}
section { clear:both; }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Math3w_C/y1kdqh4n/)**

Or you can use display:inline-block; as well :

```
.sidebar { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
.article { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Math3w_C/y1kdqh4n/1/)**

Comment: I'm sure you mean the floating elements are causing the issue (positioning is *what* you want to use in these situations)

Comment: That did not help.
@Math3w

Comment: Can you help?
@jbutler483

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want the following alignments of your Sections. I have just kept the Background Color for better understanding the Sections. Please remove the Background Color from your Production Environment. Just paste the following CSS in your Code.

```
<style>
    section {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }

        section.main {
            display: block;
            width: 75% !important;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: yellow;
            float: left;
            clear: both;
        }

    article {
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
        background: #F1F0F0;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: lawngreen;
        float: left;
    }

    sidebar {
        display: block;
        width: 215px;
        background: #F1F0F0;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: peru;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    footer {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: orange;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This just moved everything all over the place...
See [My Site](http://cms.wreckmodz.com)

article is "Welcome to WreckCMS", and sidebar is "Login". I want article and sidebar to be side-by-side. I want footer and the other elements to fall right below, not behind or around or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out on my own.

I was able to do this with the following CSS:

```
article {
display: block;
width: 55%;
background: #F1F0F0;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
float: left;
}
sidebar {
display: block;
width: 215px;
background: #F1F0F0;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left: 75%;
padding: 10px;
}
section.main {
display: block;
width: 75%;
margin: auto;
padding: 10px;
clear: both;
}
```